# Actions do CakePHP não encontradas em Vhost do Wampserver

Tags: php, cakephp, ssl, wamp

Estou a tentar fazer com que as minhas actions de administrador sejam protegidas por SSL, inclusivé a action de login. No entanto sempre que tento aceder a uma destas actions, obtenho sempre o error 404. Por exemplo, ao tentar aceder á página de login o Cake redirecciona para https://cakeprebuild.dev/login, com o error 404. O log de accesso do apache tem para cada entrada, relativamente a estas actions, "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -, neste caso para a action de login. Não tenho a certeza se o problema é do cake ou de uma má configuração do Wamp pois isto apenas acontece quando o projecto é corrido como Vhost do Wampserver, se eu tentar correr através do localhost,  `https://localhost/CakePreBuild/login`, tudo funciona perfeitamente. Como é que se pode resolver este problema?

Estou a utilizar o CakePHP 2.4.4 e o Wampserver 2.5 64bit

**UsersController**

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->deny('index');
    if (isset($this->params['admin'])) {
        $this->Security->csrfCheck = false;
        $this->Security->blackHoleCallback = 'forceSSL';
        $this->Security->requireSecure();
    }
}

public function forceSSL() {
return $this->redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $this->here);
}
```

Comment: Olá. Poderia postar onde você carrega o AuthComponent, o Controller do Login e o seu arquivo routes?
Assim vai ficar muito mais fácil.
Acredito que seja erro de permissão no controller de login e ele entra em Loop.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54203/discussion-on-question-by-jim-actions-do-cakephp-nao-encontradas-em-vhost-do-wam)

Answer (score 1):

Eu já tive problemas do SSL no cakephp, mas foi devido ao servidor está configurado erradamente

utilizei essa configuração do apache para localhost e redirecionava o http para o https apenas no .htacess

para SSL/https configuração no apache.conf

```
  <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
   </Directory>
```

para o htaccess
tente

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```